# Capture Request state at the time of an exception

Tags: php, slim

I have a Slim Framework application with a custom errorHandler, and a small middleware stack. My middleware adds attributes to the Request object which I would like to have access to from my error handler in the event of an exception. For example:

```
$app->get('/endpoint', function($request $response, $args) {
    $myAttribute = $request->getAttribute('myAttribute'); //returns 'myValue'
    throw new \Exception(); //any code that throws an error
})->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    $request = $request->withAttribute('myAttribute', 'myValue');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
});

$app->getContainer['errorHandler'] = function($c) {
    return function($request, $response, $exception) {
        $myAttribute = $request->getAttribute('myAttribute'); //returns null
        return $response;
    }
};
```

The attribute does not exist within the Request object inside the error handler because the cloned Request from inside the route has not been returned after traversing through the middleware stack. **Is it possible to access the Request and Response objects as they exist, at the time (in the location) the exception is thrown?** I can't explicitly pass them (for example, SlimException) because I'm trying to handle unexpected errors as well.

Comment: You could access the $_REQUEST superglobal I guess.

Comment: The answer is probably, no, you can't do this easily. Please note,`withAttribute()` is meant to be used to inject attributes as described in `getAttributes()` from [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#321-psrhttpmessageserverrequestinterface). Does `myAttribute` in your example fit that description? If so, there might be a workaround for your problem and if not, you might need to avoid using `withAttribute()` and consider a better approach.

Comment: @Nima, although not the only case, I'm primarily trying to get the various OAuth attributes, as described here: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/resource-server/securing-your-api/#implementation

Comment: Message objects are immutable and each modification to them causes creation of a new one, that's why you have to explicitly overwrite the object like `$request = $request->withAttri...` and pass the modified version to next middleware, so it's somehow unclear to say _as they exist_. You actually **can** pass them explicitly, and I say you should, because these data are related to this specific exception not all the others. You are not forced to handle all errors the same way, different exceptions could be handled differently, so no worries about other types of unexpected errors.

Comment: @Nima, I understand that concept, and I _am_ passing the "new" Request object to each layer of middleware. However, when an exception is thrown, it is [caught in slim](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L407) and the "new" objects are not automatically returned to that point. When the try block is triggered, any 'changes' to the Request and Response objects are disregarded because they are in a completely different scope and not automatically captured or passed anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to say, if there was a mechanism to somehow determine the latest created request object in the exception handler, same mechanism could be used to do the same in middlewares and there was no need for you to pass the request object explicitly. So I think if the exception handler *REALLY* needs to have access to the request object (and I guess it does not, it probably only needs some attributes from it) you need to explicitly pass that data to it. I can't think of any _automated_ method, because Slim does not keep track of created objects, but you can do it.

Comment: you should create your own Exception, 

something like `WithLastRequestException` which will take Request as argument of constructor + method to `getLastRequest()  ` ............

`throw new WithRequestException('some message', 0, null, $request);`

then in error handler 
`if ($exception instanceof WithRequestException) {
$exception->getLastRequest();
// do your stuff
}`

Comment: @jDolba I'm trying to handle all exceptions, not just the ones I throw myself, as I tried to explain in the last sentence of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created two, somewhat hacky, solutions to capturing Request and Response state when exceptions are thrown. Both attempt to insert a try/catch as close to the center of the middleware stack as possible (without repeating code), and involve wrapping the original exception in a new exception class together with the modified endpoint parameters.

### Middleware

This works as long as attention is paid to the order that middleware is added. Unfortunately it does require the innermost middleware is added to each route, or at the very least, "before" the middleware modifying the Request and/or Response objects. This won't catch any changes to Request/Response made inside, nor after the route.

```php
class WrappedException extends \Exception {
    public $exception;
    public $request;
    public $response;

    public function __construct($exception, $request, $response) {
        $this->exception = $exception;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
    }
}

$app->get('/endpoint', function($request $response, $args) {
    throw new \Exception(); //any code that throws an error
})->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    try {
        $response = $next($request, $response);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw new WrappedException($exception, $request, $response);
    }
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    $request = $request->withAttribute('myAttribute', 'myValue');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
});

$app->getContainer['errorHandler'] = function($c) {
    return function($request, $response, $exception) {
        if ($exception instanceof WrappedException) {
            //returns 'myValue'
            $myAttribute = $exception->request->getAttribute('myAttribute');
        }
        return $response;
    }
};
```

### Route Class

This wraps all routes in a try block, and makes for a bit cleaner route code, but you must be sure to extend all routes from the RouteBase class.

```php
class WrappedException extends \Exception {
    public $exception;
    public $request;
    public $response;

    public function __construct($exception, $request = null, $response = null) {
        $this->exception = $exception;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
    }
}

class RouteBase {
    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            try {
                $this::$method(...$arguments);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new WrappedException($e, ...$arguments);
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Route method not found.');
        }
    }
}

class RouteClass extends RouteBase {
    //PROTECTED -- must be callable by parent class, but not outside class
    protected function get(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
        throw new \Exception('A new exception!');
        $response->write('hey');
        return $response;
    }
}

$app->get('/endpoint', 'RouteClass:get');

$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    $request = $request->withAttribute('myAttribute', 'myValue');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
});

$app->getContainer['errorHandler'] = function($c) {
    return function($request, $response, $exception) {
        if ($exception instanceof WrappedException) {
            //returns 'myValue'
            $myAttribute = $exception->request->getAttribute('myAttribute');
        }
        return $response;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade to Slim 4 (if you can)

Worth noting now that Slim 4 fixes this issue. Personally, it was kind of a pain to upgrade as a lot changed, especially with the Dependency Injection containers (I went from Slim `v3.12` => `4.8`).

In Slim 4 they moved both the routing and the error handling into (separate) middlewares.